# spring kafka: filtering KafkaNull values from payload

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

My consumer configured as follows:

```
    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<List<Foo>>> consumer() {
        return message ->  {
            message.getPayload().forEach(it -> {
              // process
            })
        };
    }
```

I've also configured `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` which may produce `KafkaNull` values in message payload collection. The problem that I cannot filter such values because accessing collection with `forEach()` method produces ClassCastException:
`java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.kafka.support.KafkaNull cannot be cast to class Foo`

How can I exclude KafkaNull values from processing (without changing signature of consumer to `Consumer<Message<List<Object>>>`)?

Answer (score 3):

So we don't have a filtering function at the moment. I did raise the issue - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/issues/736

But for now the best approach for you would be to do something like this:

```
public Consumer<Message<List<Object>>> consumer() {
        return message ->  {
            message.getPayload().stream().filter(it -> it instanceof Foo).forEach(it -> {
              // process
            })
        };
}
```